# Resetting generated widget count in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, widget

Using Python 3.7 - Working in Pycharm

I am currently working on a project where I am constantly generating new widgets and removing them to show different things, and I came across a fairly annoying problem that I can't seem to figure out, let alone find information on.
When the top widget(frame) in a row of frames has been made 255 times it crashes. I guess it has something to do with how it stores the information in bytes.

Edit*

I realize that my initial explaination was more complicated than it need to so here is a simplified version:

```
from tkinter import *

list = []
for x in range(1):
    e = Frame()
    list.append(e)
print(list) #Prints .!frame

list.clear()
print(list) #Prints [], the list is now empty

for x in range(1):
    e = Frame()
    list.append(e)
print(list) #Prints .!frame2, which is one step up from the previous one even the list started empty

list[0].destroy()
list[0].forget()
print(list) #.!frame2 is still there

list.clear()

print(list) #list is now empty again

for x in range(1):
    e = Frame()
    list.append(e)
print(list) #Prints .!frame3, and it still remembers.
```

As you can see, it keeps adding to the .!frame number.

What I am looking for is a way to keep it from reaching .!frame255

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] that shows how you tried destroying the widgets. It's very difficult to understand your problem with just a description of the code.

Comment: Yes you are right, after re-reading it I realize it did not easily explain my problem. I have not added a clear example as to what is happening and what I want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the top widget(frame) in a row of frames has been made 255 times it crashes. I guess it has something to do with how it stores the information in bytes.

No, it has nothing to do with that. I think your assertion that the program crashes when the *number* reaches 255 is likely wrong. It's very easy to create a tkinter program that continues to work even when that number reaches into the thousands. If you look in the tkinter source code you'll see that it's just a plain integer that is appended to a string.

---

You seem to misunderstand the relationship between your `list` variable and the widgets that are stored in it. Clearing the list will not destroy the widgets in the list. You must delete each one individually, or destroy their parent. In this case their parent is the root window so that's not a viable solution.

If you want to destroy all of the frames, use a small loop before you clear the list:

```
for frame in list:
    frame.destroy()
```

The number that tkinter assigns to the widget is inconsequential. It doesn't matter what the number is, and it may or may not reflect how many widgets actually exist. It's an internal detail that is unimportant.

If you want to see how many widgets actually exist, you can call `winfo_children` on the root window. For that you need a reference to the root window. The easiest and best way to do that is to explicitly create the root window at the start of your code:

```
root = Tk()
```

At the end of your script you can print out all of the windows that actually exist:

```
print("all windows:", root.winfo_children())
```

In your example code it shows exactly two widgets, which is what is expected. You create a widget, then you create a second widget, then you delete *the first widget*, and then you create a third widget.

Comment: That is the thing I was trying to show though. Even if I destroy before clearing it will still keep counting. I tried to show this with the list[0].destroy, which does the same as your for loop (as long as it has just 1 entry ofc). Doing it via a for loop does not change the outcome, just tried.

Comment: _"That is the thing I was trying to show though. Even if I destroy before clearing it will still keep counting. "_ - your code doesn't illustrate that, and what you say contradicts how tkinter works. The fact that it keeps counting is inconsequential -- the number can go to 10000 and still work.

Comment: I see now, destroying before clearing does fix the problem. I thought it did not work as I could still see it keep the count. Tested it by generating one frame and clearing the list 50 000+ times with Tkinter window open. When it's done, closing the window with the x takes a long time. If I add the destroy() before clearing it's instant. So I guess that if you don't destroy, and keep generating a huge amount of frames over and over, you'll run into memory problems.